# Recursion in SQL to find a friend of a friend

Tags: sql, recursion

```
WITH Follows(Person, Friend) AS
(
    (SELECT Person, Friend FROM FaceBook)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT s.Person, s.Friend
     FROM FaceBook s, Follows f
     WHERE s.Person = f.Friend)
)
SELECT 
    s1.Person, f1.followedBy
FROM 
    FaceBook AS s1
INNER JOIN 
    Follows AS f1 ON s1.Person = f1.Person
WHERE 
    f1.followedBy NOT IN (SELECT friend FROM SocialNetwork 
                          WHERE f1.Person = s1.Person);
```

I'm trying to run a query against a `FaceBook` table. An example of my data is this

```
    Person       Friend
    -------------------
    1               2
    1               3
    1               4
```

Anyways, I want to run a recursive query that displays a recursive relation named Follows that has (p,f) pairs. Where I'm stuck is recursively returning (p,f) pairs where f follows p, but is not a direct FaceBook friend of p.

Can anyone help me walk through my current work and figure out what's wrong. I know the recursive relation is off, it's a skeleton from an earlier problem I solved. But, I'm so lost.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: This is how I was taught. Can you please send me a resource with correct format?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at this. I am still reviewing to see if I can make it better or to find an error in my logic.

This shows each person that has a friend that has a friend that is not your friend too. It then sums this so you can get a count of how many friends are friends with the potential friend. Wow, that's a mouthful:

```
SELECT
  'Michael' AS 'Person'
 ,'Rian' AS 'Friend' INTO #SOCIALNETWORK
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Rian' AS 'Person'
 ,'Michael' AS 'Friend'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Rian' AS 'Person'
 ,'New Guy 1' AS 'Friend'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Rian' AS 'Person'
 ,'New Guy 2' AS 'Friend'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'New Guy 1' AS 'Person'
 ,'Rian' AS 'Friend'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'New Guy 2' AS 'Person'
 ,'Rian' AS 'Friend'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Michael' AS 'Person'
 ,'New Guy 2' AS 'Friend'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'New Guy 2' AS 'Person'
 ,'Michael' AS 'Friend'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'New Guy 2' AS 'Person'
 ,'New Guy 3' AS 'Friend'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'New Guy 3' AS 'Person'
 ,'New Guy 2' AS 'Friend'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'New Guy 1' AS 'Person'
 ,'New Guy 2' AS 'Friend';

WITH POTENTIAL_FRIENDS
AS
(SELECT DISTINCT
    P1.Person AS 'Person'
   ,P2.Person AS 'Potential Friend'
   ,P1.Friend AS 'Friend in Common'
  FROM #SOCIALNETWORK P1
  JOIN #SOCIALNETWORK P2
    ON P1.Friend = P2.Friend
    AND P1.Person <> P2.Person
  JOIN #SOCIALNETWORK P3
    ON P1.Person = P3.Person
    AND P2.Person NOT IN (SELECT
        Friend
      FROM #SOCIALNETWORK
      WHERE #SOCIALNETWORK.Person = P3.Person))
SELECT
  POTENTIAL_FRIENDS.Person
 ,POTENTIAL_FRIENDS.[Potential Friend]
 ,COUNT(1) AS 'Number of friends in common'
FROM POTENTIAL_FRIENDS
GROUP BY POTENTIAL_FRIENDS.Person
        ,POTENTIAL_FRIENDS.[Potential Friend]
ORDER BY POTENTIAL_FRIENDS.Person
, POTENTIAL_FRIENDS.[Potential Friend]


DROP TABLE #SOCIALNETWORK
```